# How to change duplicates with dynamic data by replace() in Vanilla Js

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I need fix one problem, now I'm try to describe task itself.

My task is create a function that turns a string into a Mexican Wave - [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_(audience))

Input(string) => Output([array])

for example Input('wow') => Output('Wow', 'wOw', 'woW')

Now I created function and all do fine, except duplicates and spaces

```js
function wave(str) {
  let arr = [];
  let arrUpperSymbols = [];
  let res = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    arr.push(str);
    arrUpperSymbols.push(arr[i].charAt(i).toUpperCase());

    res.push(arr[i].replace(arr[i].charAt(i), arrUpperSymbols[i]));
  }
  console.log(res);
}

wave("sigrid");
```

Its return ["Sigrid","sIgrid",siGrid","sigRid","sIgrid","sigriD"]
But I need to UpperCase one letter by one itaration in rotation and duplicates dynamically, 
I'm tried wrapp arr[i].charAt(i) in //g but its not work.

I'll be appreciate for any help, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to use `slice` to update any value at any particular index of string. Return the part of string before and after the current letter as it is and change the letter at current index.

```js
function wave(str) {
  let res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    res.push(str.slice(0, i) + str[i].toUpperCase() + str.slice(i + 1));
    //       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //       part before i     letter at i            part after i
  }
  console.log(res);
}

wave("sigrid");
```

You can also create an array on length `str.length` and use `map()` on it.

```js
const wave = str => Array(str.length).fill().map((x,i) => str.slice(0, i) + str[i].toUpperCase() + str.slice(i + 1))

console.log(wave("sigrid"));
```

Comment: Oh super, thanks for help, do you know any thought how iterate these letters avoiding spaces, maybe method or I need to create if/else, if str has a space?
And skip spaces by this way?

Comment: @KolesnikVladislav Try wrapping `res.push(...)`; in `if` block like `if(str[i] !== ' '){res.push(...)}`

Comment: very helpful for me, really powerful method for working with string, thank you very much man!